# Button placement

Tags: java, applet, jbutton, layout-manager

I want `money1` button to be below the `Jlabel` saying `fillmeup` but when I do try to add a button it goes to the right of Label not under it. I am using an applet and using `JButtons`. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here is the GUI picture [image]

[The blackJack game I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYE0b.png)

```
    setBackground( new Color(130,50,40) );
    setLayout( new BorderLayout(3,3) );

    BlackjackCanvas board = new BlackjackCanvas();
    add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);      

    Panel buttonPanel = new Panel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(220,200,180));
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Panel buttonPane2 = new Panel();
    buttonPane2.setBackground(new Color(220,200,180));
    add(buttonPane2, BorderLayout.EAST);

    Panel buttonPane3 = new Panel();
    buttonPane3.setBackground(new Color(220,200,180));
    add(buttonPane3, BorderLayout.WEST);

    Button hit = new Button( "Hit!" );
    hit.addActionListener(board);
    hit.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    buttonPanel.add(hit);

    Button stand = new Button( "Stand!" );
    stand.addActionListener(board);
    stand.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    buttonPanel.add(stand);

    Button newGame = new Button( "New Game" );
    newGame.addActionListener(board);
    newGame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    buttonPanel.add(newGame);

    JLabel money = new JLabel( "Fill me up!" );
    money.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    buttonPane2.add(money);

    Button money1 = new Button( "A rare commodity" );
    newGame.addActionListener(board);
    newGame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    buttonPane2.add(money1);
```

Comment: Please **don't** link to images on other website. Use the image tool inside the editor instead. If you link to external sources and they die for some reason, the resource will not be accessible anymore, making the question hard to understand.

Comment: @BackSlash it would not let me add pictures to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider referring to the docs here [Java Layout Options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

And setting buttonPane2 layout manager to the one that meets your needs.

This can be done using setLayout(new xxxLayout());

Comment: Steven Kirby, I used the box layout and it works. Thanks